# NextJS Dynamic Rendering

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, next.js

Long time developer finally picking up Next.js, so I know this is probably going to boil down to something silly. Here goes. What's wrong with my `getStaticPaths()` value here? It seems like I've formatted it exactly as the docs require. (Value being assigned to `paths` is `console.log()`'d in the terminal window)

[image]

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const paths = getEvents();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    };
};
```

And the `getEvents()` function:

```
export const getEvents = () => {
    axios.post(`${globals.api_endpoint}getEvents.php`, {
        action: 'getStaticPaths'
    }).then((r) => {
        if (!r.data.error) {
            const paths = r.data.map(index => {
                return {
                    params: {
                        id: index.event_id
                    }
                };
            });
            console.log(paths);
            return paths;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getStaticPath` is an async function. If you're doing something like this `paths` will always be a Promise here.

```
const paths = getEvents();
return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
};
```

You should use an await keyword here to wait for the results:

```
const paths = await getEvents();
```

and in the `getEvents` function you should return all the axios.post call, like so:

```
return axios.post(`${globals.api_endpoint}getEvents.php`, {...
```

Additionally, I don't know how your api endpoint looks but the api path should look like this: `${globals.api_endpoint}/getEvents.php`. Your api endpoint shouldn't have the slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Gorgeous. Thanks, @krybinski for the help. Of *course* it's returning a promise. The mistake wasn't quite as silly as I expected, but something simple, for sure.

```
export const getEvents = async () => {
    return axios.post(`${globals.api_endpoint}getEvents.php`, {
        action: 'getStaticPaths'
    });
};


export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const response = await getEvents();
    const paths = response.data.map(event => {
        return {
            params: {
                id: event.event_id
            }
        }
    });
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    };
};
```